# Inner Join for 3 tables with SUM of two columns in SQL Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

I have the following three tables:

[image: Table Customer]

[image: Table Sales]

[image: Table Sales_Payment]

I have Following Query to Join Above 3 Tables

```
     customer.customer_id,
     customer.name,
     SUM(sales.total),
     sales.created_at,
     SUM(sales_payments.amount)
FROM
     sales INNER JOIN customer ON customer.customer_id = sales.customer_id
     INNER JOIN sales_payments ON sales.customer_id = sales_payments.customer_id
WHERE sales.created_at ='2020-04-03'
GROUP By customer.name
```

Result for Above Query is given below
[image: Query Output]

Sum of `sales.total` is double of the actual sum of sales.total column which has 2-row count, I need to have the actual SUM of that column, without doubling the SUM of those rows, Thank you, for your help in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

The problem here is that there are consecutive inner joins and the number of rows getting fetched in the second inner join is not restricted. So, as we have not added a condition on sales_payment_id in the join between the sales and sales_payment tables, one row in sales table(for customer_id 2, in this case) would be mapped to 2 rows in the payment table. This causes the same values to be reconsidered.
In other words, the mapping for customer_id 2 between the 3 tables is 1:1:2 rather than 1:1:1.

**SOLUTION**

Solution 1 : As mentioned by Gordon, you could first aggregate the amount values of the sales_payments table and then aggregate the values in sales table.

Solution 2 : Alternatively (IMHO a better approach), you could add a foreign key between sales and sales_payment tables. For example, the sales_payment_id column of sales_payment table can be introduced in the sales table as well. This would facilitate the join between these tables and reduce additional overheads while querying data.

The query would then look like:

```
`SELECT c.customer_id,
  c.name,
  SUM(s.total),
  s.created_at,
  SUM(sp.amount)
FROM customer c
INNER JOIN sales s
ON c.customer_id = s.customer_id
INNER JOIN sales_payments sp
ON c.customer_id        = sp.customer_id
AND s.sales_payments_id = sp.sales_payments_id
WHERE s.created_at      ='2020-04-03'
GROUP BY c.customer_id,
c.name,
s.created_at ;`
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Gordon Linof's Answer worked for me, and when I execute your query I got following error  "Unknown Column 's.sales_payment_id' anyway thanks for your effort & intention to help"

Comment: Yeah, that is the reason my advice was that " the sales_payment_id of sales_payment tables can be introduced in the sales table as well". We needed to add the sales_payment_id column in the sales table for this. But cool, glad that the problem was solved. :)

Comment: Hi Mohamed, I am not able to add a comment on Gordon's answer due to reputation restraints. 
But I think if you remove the SUM function call from SUM(sp.amount) in the final select, it should work there, i.e, 
    `SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, SUM(s.total),
       s.created_at, sp.amount
       FROM customer c JOIN ....`
And you'll need to add sp.amount in the GROUP BY as well at the end.

We are doing this because we have already aggregated the sales_payment_amount in the join below. Hope this is useful!

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple rows for `sales_payments` and `sales` per customer.  You need to pre-aggregate to get the right value:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.name, s.created_at, s.total, sp.amount
FROM customer c JOIN
     (SELECT s.customer_id, s.created_at, SUM(s.total) as total
      FROM sales s
      WHERE s.created_at ='2020-04-03'
      GROUP BY s.customer_id, s.created_at
     ) s
     ON c.customer_id = s.customer_id JOIN
     (SELECT sp.customer_id, SUM(sp.amount) as amount
      FROM sales_payments sp
      GROUP BY sp.customer_id
     ) sp
     ON s.customer_id = sp.customer_id
```

Comment: Your answer was working for `s.total` but now 'sp.amount' is doubled now, is there any solutions to overcome this issue

Comment: @MohamedFarookMohamedFazrin . . . Then you need to aggregate both of them before `JOIN`ing and no outer aggregation is needed.

Comment: @MohamedFarookMohamedFazrin . . . Does the revised version not work?